# Problemas con Paquetes en JAVA

Tags: java, packages

el problema que estoy teniendo con los paquetes es el siguiente:
necesito modelar un sistema carcelario, por el cual tengo que crear distintas clases como Carcel,MaximaSeguridad y MinimaSeguridad estas se deben encontrar en el    paquete    um.prog1.carcel.
En  el  paquete um.prog1 se debe colocar las clases SistemaPenitenciario y las interfaces deben colocar en  el paquete um.prog1.interfaces.
Ademas la clase Principal se encontrara en el paquete um.prog1  ,
Me quedo de la siguiente forma:

```
    package um.prog1.carcel;
    public class Carcel{
       //codigo
    }


      package um.prog1.carcel;
      public class MaximaSeguridad{
        //codigo       
      }

    package um.prog1.carcel;
    public class MinimaSeguridad{
        //codigo
}

   package um.prog1;
   public class SistemaPenitenciario{
      // codigo
}

  package um.prog1.interfaces;
  public class Interface{
    //codigo
}

  package um.prog1;
  public class Principal{
  public static void main(String[]args){
    //codigo
}
}
```

El tema es que cuando quiero compilarlo desde la cmd no se si tengo que posicionarme en mi source folder que y lo compilaria **javac um\prog1\Principal.java** . Pero no se como poner para ejecutarlo , ya probe cambiando \ por punto pero me dice Error: no se ha encontrado o cargado la clase principal. No se si talvez sea un error en la definicion de package en las clases o si estoy poniendo mal para ejecutarlo.

Comment: como lo estás ejecutando?

Comment: el tema es ese no se si lo estoy ejecutando bien , lo probe de estas 2 maneras: java  um\prog1\Principal y java um.prog1.Principal